# or-like feature in case … of statement? Or maybe a more generic pattern?

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, design-patterns, case, matching

I've been learning Erlang for a while now, and for to learn it I'm writing a IRC bot. This IRC bot should listen to commands in the „!command“ and the „Nick: command“ form. I pre-parse the IRC protocol so that I have to match the send message only. I'm doing this with binary patterns like this:

```
case Msg of
    [Nick, _, <<"PRIVMSG">>, <<"#",Channel/binary>>, <<"!rock">>] ->
        irckybot_api:privmsg(<<"#",Channel/binary>>, [Nick, choose_hand(rock)]),
        {ok, State};
    [Nick, _, <<"PRIVMSG">>, <<"#",Channel/binary>>, <<BNick:Len/binary,": rock">>] ->
        irckybot_api:privmsg(<<"#",Channel/binary>>, [Nick, choose_hand(rock)]),
        {ok, State};
end
```

Am I right that I have to write two patterns for this? Can't I consolidate the two patterns to one? Maybe with a more generic pattern? I don't really know…

LG,
 CK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it could be better written as :

```
case Msg of
  [Nick, _, <<"PRIVMSG">>, <<"#",Channel/binary>>, X] ->
    case X of
       <<"!rock">> -> ....;
       <<BNick:Len/binary,": rock">> -> .......
    end;
  _ -> .......
end
```

Comment: This is much better, yes, thanks. But I still have to repeat the code of the response. I can't spare it, can I?

Comment: you could write a function "create_response(X) -> irckybot_api:privmsg...." that constructs the response based on the value of X .. rock -or- BNick.. and call that function inside the inner case clause..

Comment: Yes, you are right. But that's not what I want. I want to hit it with one case, is it possible? Anyway, thanks for your pations and answers :)